# Printing column names on the same line

Tags: java

I want to print column names, below is my code

```
 for ( int k=1 ; k< columnCount+1;k++){
      System.out.println(columnNames[k] + "   ");
 }
```

How do I print the values as columns?

I want

```
value 1   value 2  value 3
```

not

```
value1
value2
value3
```

Comment: `System.out.print(columnNames[k] + "\t");`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simplest way is to use

```
System.out.print(columnNames[k] + "   ");
```

`ln` in `println` means that you want to add new line mark at the end of printed line.

---

Also as [Reimeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871026/reimeus) pointed in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654378/printing-column-names-on-the-same-line/14654382#comment20477973_14654378) you can use tabulator `"\t"` instead of fixed number of spaces.

---

But IMHO since you are using it to print columns you should use `System.out.format` (or `System.out.printf`) to print fixed amount of characters like

```
System.out.format("[%-10s]", "name");// output [name      ]
System.out.format("[%10s]", "name");//  output [      name]
```

More info in [Formatter class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println` adds a new line. Look at `ln` suffix. You have to use `System.out.print`.