# How can I print the contents of an ArrayList in a specific way?

Tags: java

How can I print the contents of an ArrayList in a specific way, in Java?
For example:

```
System.out.println("A        B");
System.out.println("100     100");
System.out.println("200     200");
System.out.println("300     300");
```

How can I do this with an ArrayList?

I write the array list like this:

```
ArrayList mathChoices = new ArrayList(3); 
mathChoices.add("100");
mathChoices.add("200");
mathChoices.add("300");

ArrayList historyChoices = new ArrayList(3);
historyChoices.add("100");
historyChoices.add("200");
historyChoices.add("300");
```

And it prints out like this:

```
Math        History
[100, 200, 300] [100, 200, 300]
```

I want to print out "MATH" and then "HISTORY" with vertical columns of 100,200,300 under each word. 
It is supposed to be like the questions in the game show Jeopardy.

Comment: Please try to put a little more effort into writing a clear and unambiguous question. Please also show what you've tried and explain a bit how it's not working.

Comment: OK, I'll vote to re-open. You will want to learn to use a single for loop to loop through the ArrayLists together.

Comment: In fact, while waiting for the question to be re-opened, why don't you try that now and post your effort -- use a for loop, create a String inside of the loop that gets info from both ArrayLists, and then prints out that String, and see what you can come up with.

Comment: Don't use the raw type `ArrayList`, parametrize it: `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: Question is well enough phrased now, please reopen this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments, so here is the updated answer:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-20s %s" , "Mathematics", "History" ));

for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    System.out.println(String.format("%-20s %s" , mathChoices.get(i), historyChoices.get(i)));    
}
```

The output will be as you requested.

Comment: `\t` will work for this case but for more general scenario where there could be longer headers like "Mathematics" instead of "Math" it is better to use `System.out.printf` or `System.out.format` like in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14654382/1393766)

Comment: Yep, agree with @Pshemo -- tabs are definitely not the way to do this. Besides, let's not write the OP's code for him but rather guide him with suggestions.

Comment: I totally agree, my mistake.
Even though it would have worked in this case, it is the wrong way to learn it. The answer has been updated.